# Create database overwrote my data from recently copied data from s3 bucket

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE "Orders";

I did not set any permissions on this database. Another person at my company ran the SQL above and replaced the data. How can I prevent this from happening in the future using the permissions in Snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR: The global privilege [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#global-privileges) in Snowflake permits a user/role to run such a statement. Removing it requires designing a role based access system and revoking administrative level rights from existing users.*

At the very minimum, severely restrict the users who are allowed to run statements as [`ACCOUNTADMIN`, `SECURITYADMIN` or `SYSADMIN` roles](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#using-the-accountadmin-role). Revoke these privileges from the set of users you want to prevent from performing `DATABASE` level operations:

```sql
REVOKE accountadmin FROM USER other_user1;
REVOKE securityadmin FROM USER other_user1;
REVOKE sysadmin FROM USER other_user1;

REVOKE accountadmin FROM USER other_user2;
REVOKE securityadmin FROM USER other_user2;
REVOKE sysadmin FROM USER other_user2;

(… repeat for all users that need to be limited …)
```

Next, [design custom roles](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#creating-a-role-hierarchy) and define a desired level of accesses over them. Also decide which usernames will belong to each role depending on their function in your organization.

The following is a very generic and basic example just for illustrative purposes that divides all "Orders" database users into two levels of access. Specific needs will vary depending on your organization's unique situation.

```sql
CREATE ROLE orders_read_and_write;
CREATE ROLE orders_read_only;

-- Snowflake recommends you create a hierarchy of roles so you can allow any
-- SYSADMIN-allowed users to manage these newly created roles instead of
-- requiring an ACCOUNTADMIN level user to do so in future
GRANT ROLE orders_read_and_write TO ROLE sysadmin;
GRANT ROLE orders_read_only TO ROLE sysadmin;
```

The two roles `orders_read_and_write` and `orders_read_only` created above can then be granted privileges appropriately to control their level of access for schema and tables under the "Orders" database. Continuing the example:

```sql
-- Allow both these roles to access schema and tables under "Orders" DB
-- This does not allow them to perform any DB-level operations
-- such as replacing/overwriting it

GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE "Orders" TO ROLE orders_read_and_write;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE "Orders" TO ROLE orders_read_only;

-- Allow read and write access appropriately to schema under the DB
-- Note the difference on using ALL vs. USAGE in the privilege granted
-- to each role here:

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "Orders"."SCHEMA-NAME" TO ROLE orders_read_and_write;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "Orders"."SCHEMA-NAME" TO ROLE orders_read_only;
GRANT SELECT
  ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "Orders"."SCHEMA-NAME"
  TO ROLE orders_read_only;
```

Finally, grant the roles to their respective username(s).

```sql
GRANT ROLE orders_read_and_write TO USER other_user_1;

GRANT ROLE orders_read_only TO USER other_user_2;

(…)
```

Any role lacking the [`CREATE DATABASE` level privilege](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#global-privileges) will no longer be able to perform a statement such as `CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE "Orders";`.

In the above example, both roles only receive `USAGE` level access on the `Orders` database, which does not permit them to run such statements anymore.

If you ever need to permit such a privilege to a role, you can `GRANT` it explicitly to the role of choice that has trusted users under it:

```sql
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO ROLE role_name;
```

I highly recommend going over Snowflake's [Access Controls feature](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control.html) section a few times to get acclimated to the terminology. This makes it easier to implement and manage effective access controls in your organization.

**Note**: Introducing access control is a wide-impacting change and will require communication and coordination within your organization to be truly effective. It is always difficult to remove freedoms as this may be ingrained into scripts and programs already in use.